# Are there any functions in the stl which do string conversion, but with a length parameter?

Tags: c++, stl

Let say you have a string:

```
std::string s = "ABCD\t1234";
```

I can use `std::string::find` to get an offset to the '\t' character, but as far as I know there are no functions with the following signature:

```
int atoi_n(char *, int len);
```

An I missing anything? `strtok` replaces the `\t` with `\0`, and I don't want to touch the original buffer. I find it hard to believe that there aren't instances of the `atoi`, `atof`, etc which take a length parameter, but I can't find anything.

Anyone know if there is something I'm missing? I know boost has some tokenizers but I'd like avoid having to add the dependency of boost.

Looking the comments so far I'd like to clarify. Let's change the scenario:
char buffer[1024];
char *pStartPos;
char *pEndPost;
pStartPos = buffer + 5;
pEndPos = buffer + 10;

Let's also say you can't make any assumptions about the memory outside pStartPos and pEndPos. How do you convert the charaters between pStartPos and pEndPos to an int without adding a '\0' to buffer or copying using substr?

Comment: Just use `std::stoi` with `substr()`.

Comment: I totally don't see the problem...  Why do you need to pass the length?  And how is that related to _preceeding_ characters?

Comment: I know one good reason for there not being an `atoi` like that. The non-const `char *` parameter is just an unnecessary burden to use.

Comment: chris - close but no cigar. Thanks for pointing std::stoi out though. The issue is that I want to be explicit as to how long the buffer is without having to rely on a \0.

Comment: A few points: 1) substr() of a number is cheap with short string optimization. 2) Boost is probably the most portable library you could have in your program, including the standard library that came with your compiler (i.e. a different environment might not support all the standard functionality your current standard library is providing you). 3) Do you really want to stop parsing at any arbitrary point, even halfway through a number? The standard number-parsing functions stop only when encountering the first non-digit char, which is usually the best approach.

Comment: The reason I want to stop at any arbitrary point is because the buffer is not a null terminated string. That means I don't want functions like atoi to try to convert a number past the end of the buffer.

The scenario is that I have a buffer and two offsets, the beginning where I want to parse, and the end of the buffer. I don't want atoi to start parsing possibly invalid data.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to parse only the end of the string (from the character after `\t` to the end) you just need to pass a pointer to the first character to parse to `atoi`...

```
int n = atoi(s.c_str()+s.find('\t')+1);
```

(error checking omitted for brevity - in particular, we are always assuming that a `\t` is actually present)

If, instead, you want to parse from the beginning of the string up to `\t` you can just do

```
int n = atoi(s.c_str());
```

since `atoi` stops at the first non-numeric character anyway.

By the way, you should consider using more robust solutions for parsing the number, like `strtol`, `sscanf` or the C++ streams - they all can report a parsing error in some way, while `atoi` just returns `0` (which isn't distinguishable from a 0 that comes from parsing the string).

---

Incidentally, `atoi` is not in the "STL" by any means - it's just part of the C standard library.

---

> I know that atoi is not in the STL. I was wondering if there was anything in STL like it where you can specify the last character which you want to include in the conversion. Basically I have a buffer which may be partially filled with garbage. I know the start of possible valid data and the end of possible valid data. I don't want to depend on whitespace to end the conversion, I want to be explicit about the length of the "field" because it also may not be /0 terminated.

If you are sure that the garbage doesn't start with digits you can use `atoi`/`strtol`/`istringstream` as is - they automatically stop just when they see the garbage. Otherwise, use the `substr` method to extract the exact substring you need:

```
std::string mayContainGarbage="alcak123456amaclmò";
std::string onlyTheDigits=mayContainGarbage.substr(5, 6);
// now parse onlyTheDigits as you prefer
```

Comment: I know that atoi is not in the STL. I was wondering if there was anything in STL like it where you can specify the last character which you want to include in the conversion.
Basically I have a buffer which may be partially filled with garbage. I know the start of possible valid data and the end of possible valid data. I don't want to depend on whitespace to end the conversion, I want to be explicit about the length of the "field" because it also may not be /0 terminated.

Comment: @bpeikes: "STL" is no longer a useful term. It used to stand for `Standard Template Library` back in 1996, but it was merged into the C++ Standard Library. With all the enhancements to the Standard Library in C++11, you now can't say what is still STL. String processing never was, though - `std::string` preceded the STL integration.

Comment: Thanks. What do you call the std:: functions then? The standard library?

Comment: @bpeikes: yes. Personally, I still use "STL" to refer *only to the containers/algorithms part* of the standard library, but that's frowned upon. Certainly you don't use "STL" to refer to legacy C functions.

Comment: @MSalters The STL is part of the Standard Library but is still refered to as the STL. "_The STL consists of the iterator, container, algorithm and function object parts of the standard library._" (from "The C++ Programming Language", Fourth Edition, Chp. 31, p. 885 by Bjarne Stroustrup) So even in 2013 the creator of C++ doesn't seem to think the term "STL" is "no longer useful".

Comment: I was really hoping to not have to perform a copy with substr. I'm surprised that to get a atoi(char *str, int len) function, I'd have to write one myself by copying atoi. Also note that an atoi function which took a len could also be more efficient int that it could parse it from least significant digit to most significant digit.

Comment: @bpeikes: you can alway modify it in place to add a `\0` and restore it afterwards...

Comment: @MatteoItalia: The issue is what happens when the buffer that you are trying to atoi is not null terminated. I was hoping that since there are now functions which help prevent buffer overruns, that their might be a sscanf which allowed you to set the maximum number of characters to attempt to parse.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no such function out-of-box, but it shouldn't be difficult to implement.

For example:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
int range_to_int(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator past_end) {

    if (begin != past_end) {

        bool negative = false;

        auto ch = *begin;
        if (ch == '-') {
            negative = true;
            ++begin;
        }
        else if (ch == '+')
            ++begin;

        if (begin != past_end) {

            int result = 0;

            do {
                auto ch = *begin;
                if (ch < '0' || ch > '9')
                    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid digit.");
                result = result * 10 + (ch - '0');
                ++begin;
            } while (begin != past_end);

            if (negative)
                result = -result;

            return result;

        }

        throw std::invalid_argument("+ or - must be followed by at least one digit.");

    }

    throw std::invalid_argument("Empty range.");

}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
int main() {

    const char* buffer = "abc-123def";

    int i = range_to_int(buffer + 4, buffer + 7);
    assert(i == 123);

    i = range_to_int(buffer + 3, buffer + 7);
    assert(i == -123);

    try {
        i = range_to_int(buffer + 3, buffer + 8);
        assert(false);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    try {
        i = range_to_int(buffer + 3, buffer + 4);
        assert(false);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    try {
        i = range_to_int(buffer + 4, buffer + 4);
        assert(false);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    // You can use it on std::string as well....

    const std::string str = buffer;

    i = range_to_int(str.begin() + 4, str.begin() + 7);
    assert(i == 123);

    // Etc...

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```